# Getting errors while I run my app due to dependencies

Tags: android

I am getting errors when I build or run the app on emulator

> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong: Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
>
>   > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugAnnotationProcessorClasspath'.
>   >     Could not find com.github.bumptech.glide:compile:4.11.0.
>   >      Searched in the following locations:
>
>   Required by:
>          project :app
>
>   > Could not find com.jakewharton:butterknife-compile:10.2.1.
>
>   - file:/C:/Users/Noel/AndroidStudioProjects/EBawarchi7/app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compile/10.2.1/butterknife-compile-10.2.1.pom
>   - file:/C:/Users/Noel/AndroidStudioProjects/EBawarchi7/app/node_modules/react-native/android/com/jakewharton/butterknife-compile/10.2.1/butterknife-compile-10.2.1.jar
>       Required by:
>        project :app
> - Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 25s

My Gradle(app)

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'io.fabric'

    android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.e_bawarchi"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 29
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

}

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])



    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.2.1'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
    implementation 'com.asksira.android:loopingviewpager:1.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.11.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compile:4.11.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compile:10.2.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.basgeekball:awesome-validation:4.2'

    implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
}        
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My gradle project

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        maven { url 'http://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'}
        maven { url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/'}
        maven { url '$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android'}
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'



        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
            maven { url 'http://maven.google.com'}
            maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
            maven { url 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/'}
            maven { url 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/'}
            maven { url '$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android'}
            jcenter()

    }
}

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

I am not able to resolve this issue because I am new to Android studio

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `mavenCentral()` to your repositories in project level `build.gradle` file.

```
repositories {
  mavenCentral()
  google()
  ......
}
```